# Program keeps looping in an infinite function?

Tags: python

Currently working on a Rock Paper Scissors game for a basic python class. I've been working on it for about the past week, as I looked up how to make a basic python game and stumbled upon an article here and went off of it. Not sure why though, but it keeps looping. I want to keep the structure similar to this also, as my instructor asked me to keep it like this.

I've tried changing cpu_rand and cpu_choice, and also putting the function results() in different locations but also did not work.

```
import random #import random module
import sys #import system module
def playgame():
    while True:
        player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
        cpu_rand = random.randint(1,3) #Generate random integer 1-3
        cpu_choice = None
        if cpu_rand == 1: #if cpu_choice = 1, cpu_choice = "Rock"
            cpu_choice = "Rock"
        elif cpu_rand == 2: #if cpu_choice = 2, cpu_choice = "Scissors"
            cpu_choice = "Scissors"
        elif cpu_rand == 3: #if cpu_choice = 3, cpu_choice = "Paper"
            cpu_choice = "Paper"
def results(): #check results of player choice v computer choice
    play_again = None #Sets this to null for future reference, for asking if playing again.
    if(player_choice == cpu_choice):    #Tie
        print("It's a Tie")
        play_again = input("Retry?")
    #Rock Outcomes
    elif(player_choice == "Rock" and cpu_choice == "Scissors"):
        print("You Win!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    elif(player_choice == "Rock" and cpu_choice == "Paper"):
        print("You Lose!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    #Paper Outcomes
    elif(player_choice == "Paper" and cpu_choice == "Scissors"):
        print("You Lose!")
        play_again = input("Play again?cpu")
    elif(player_choice == "Paper" and cpu_choice == "Rock"):
        print("You Win!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    #Scissors Outcomes
    elif(player_choice == "Scissors" and cpu_choice == "Rock"):
        print("You Lose!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    elif(player_choice == "Scissors" and cpu_choice == "Paper"):
        print("You Win!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")

    if play_again == "Yes": #if elif play again statements, from if/elif statements, play_again is changed to an input
        playgame()
    elif play_again == "No":
        print("You Lose!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Command")
        play_again = input("play again?")
        return play_again
    results()

def start():
    while True:
        gamestart = input("You ready to play some Rock, Paper, Scissors? (y/n)")
        if gamestart == "y":
                playgame()
                return gamestart
        elif gamestart == "n":
            print("Game Over!")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Command")
start()
```

The result I was looking to be returned was everything under the results function, so if player_choice == cpu_choice then it would print out what is under that. Instead it loops back to "Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"

Comment: In `play_game`, what is the condition that causes you to exit `while True`?

Comment: You didn't actually ***call*** the `results` function... You need to call it inside `playgame` function and probably make it take two arguments so you can call it as `results(player_choice, cpu_choice)`

Answer (score 0):

You never called the results function in your code so it never ran.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `results()`. Moreover player_choice and cpu_choice were local variables in `playgame()`.

```
import random #import random module
import sys #import system module
def playgame():
    while True:
        player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
        cpu_rand = random.randint(1,3) #Generate random integer 1-3
        cpu_choice = None
        if cpu_rand == 1: #if cpu_choice = 1, cpu_choice = "Rock"
            cpu_choice = "Rock"
        elif cpu_rand == 2: #if cpu_choice = 2, cpu_choice = "Scissors"
            cpu_choice = "Scissors"
        elif cpu_rand == 3: #if cpu_choice = 3, cpu_choice = "Paper"
            cpu_choice = "Paper"
        results(player_choice, cpu_choice)
def results(player_choice, cpu_choice): #check results of player choice v computer choice
    play_again = None #Sets this to null for future reference, for asking if playing again.
    if(player_choice == cpu_choice):    #Tie
        print("It's a Tie")
        play_again = input("Retry?")
    #Rock Outcomes
    elif(player_choice == "Rock" and cpu_choice == "Scissors"):
        print("You Win!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    elif(player_choice == "Rock" and cpu_choice == "Paper"):
        print("You Lose!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    #Paper Outcomes
    elif(player_choice == "Paper" and cpu_choice == "Scissors"):
        print("You Lose!")
        play_again = input("Play again?cpu")
    elif(player_choice == "Paper" and cpu_choice == "Rock"):
        print("You Win!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    #Scissors Outcomes
    elif(player_choice == "Scissors" and cpu_choice == "Rock"):
        print("You Lose!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")
    elif(player_choice == "Scissors" and cpu_choice == "Paper"):
        print("You Win!")
        play_again = input("Play again?")

    if play_again == "Yes": #if elif play again statements, from if/elif statements, play_again is changed to an input
        playgame()
    elif play_again == "No":
        print("You Lose!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Command")
        play_again = input("play again?")
        return play_again
    results()

def start():
    while True:
        gamestart = input("You ready to play some Rock, Paper, Scissors? (y/n)")
        if gamestart == "y":
                playgame()
                return gamestart
        elif gamestart == "n":
            print("Game Over!")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Command")
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so dense and repetitive, may I suggest another approach?:

```
import random
wins = [
    ('paper', 'rock'),   # paper wins over rock
    ('rock', 'scissors'),
    ('scissors', 'paper'),
]
items = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def computer_choice():
    return random.choice(items)

def player_choice():
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        print i, item
    while 1:
        choice = input("choose [0..%d]: " % (len(items)-1))
        if 0 <= choice < len(items):
            break
    return items[choice]

while 1:
    cpu = computer_choice()
    human = player_choice()
    print "CPU: %s, HUMAN: %s" % (cpu, human)
    if cpu == human:
        print 'tie..'
    elif (cpu, human) in wins:
        print "CPU wins."
    else:
        print "HUMAN wins."
    again = raw_input("play again? [q to quit]: ")
    print
    if again.lower() == 'q':
        break
```

sample session:

```
0 rock
1 paper
2 scissors
choose [0..2]: 0
CPU: scissors, HUMAN: rock
HUMAN wins.
play again? [q to quit]:

0 rock
1 paper
2 scissors
choose [0..2]: 1
CPU: paper, HUMAN: paper
tie..
play again? [q to quit]:

0 rock
1 paper
2 scissors
choose [0..2]: 1
CPU: scissors, HUMAN: paper
CPU wins.
play again? [q to quit]:
```

the only changes to make this play rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock (https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Rock,_Paper,_Scissors,_Lizard,_Spock) are:

```
wins = [
    ('scissors', 'paper'),   # Scissors cuts Paper 
    ('paper', 'rock'),       # Paper covers Rock 
    ('rock', 'lizard'),      # Rock crushes Lizard 
    ('lizard', 'spock'),     # Lizard poisons Spock 
    ('spock', 'scissors'),   # Spock smashes Scissors
    ('scissors', 'lizard'),  # Scissors decapitates Lizard
    ('lizard', 'paper'),     # Lizard eats Paper
    ('paper', 'spock'),      # Paper disproves Spock
    ('spock', 'rock'),       # Spock vaporizes Rock
    ('rock', 'scissors'),    # (and as it always has) Rock crushes Scissors 
]
items = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock']
```

sample run

```
0 rock
1 paper
2 scissors
3 lizard
4 spock
choose [0..4]: 4
CPU: scissors, HUMAN: spock
HUMAN wins.
play again? [q to quit]:

0 rock
1 paper
2 scissors
3 lizard
4 spock
choose [0..4]: 2
CPU: spock, HUMAN: scissors
CPU wins.
play again? [q to quit]:
```